# Should we give users a link to their question that has no activity in over a year?

Tags: feature-request, review, notifications

Users occasionally forget about the questions they asked. These are questions that may require editing or review to obtain more acceptable answers. Would it be appropriate to remind OPs with a link to a dead (but not closed) question to encourage them to review or edit it? Perhaps the link could be given in an alert after the question has been dead (and unaccepted) for a year or longer.

Comment: I think the only time such users have motivation to improve “dead” Qs is when they get warned about a potential Q ban, or more frequently after one is already imposed. At that time they’re usually pretty motivated to go through their own history. The “dead” ones are the low hanging fruit, they’ll pick that first. Closed is worse, deleted is the real obstacle. In short, I think reminding them of dead questions they lost interest in will have minimal impact until they hit a ban, and then it’s superfluous. Just my $0.02.